# jQuery $(this) first child selection for input

Tags: jquery, iteration, each, css-selectors

I've always used a `tempClass` to iterate through something and select first child text input. I am having weird issues with this now. I've looked off and on to with no success to find the proper way to do this.

**Code Snippet**

```
$( ".inputQuantityUpdate" ).each(function( index ) {
    $(this).addClass("tempPtr");
    completed   = $(".tempPtr :input[type='text']:first").val();
    nc          = $(".tempPtr :input[type='text']:first").next().val();
    if(nc == "NC")nc = 0;
    $(this).removeClass("tempPtr");
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

My problem is nc and completed is correct for the first iteration, but not after.
For some reason this isn't working. What would be the best way to tackle this?

Update:
The marked solution worked. I should have posted the other fields I am grabbing because they aren't working. This set of routines works when only 1 element "inputQuantityUpdate" is in the iteration. It blows up when there are multiple. I have a feeling this is some sort of memory issue/syntax misuse on my part. What is the best way to do this if there is data stored in the element like:

```
function updatesConfirmed(){
        $("#confirmInputValues").remove();
        $( ".inputQuantityUpdate" ).each(function( index ) {
            job         = $(this).data("job");
            suf         = $(this).data("suff");
            op          = $(this).data("op");
            completed   = $(":input[type='text']:first", this).val();
            nc          = $(":input[type='text']:first", this).next().val();
            if(nc == "NC")nc = 0;
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Well, your each loop is essentially pointless. Why you say? Well, on your first line you assign the element a class of tempPtr, that's all fine. Next line, you select the elements .tempPtr and the first text input, every loop, this will be the same value every time

Comment: You may not want to use an `each` loop for this because you do the same thing on each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to grab the first text input from your current element, in which case your selectors would change to:

```
completed   = $(":input[type='text']:first", this).val();
nc          = $(":input[type='text']:first", this).next().val();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's the case that you're only using `tempPtr` to access the looped element in each loop.  If that's the case, you can use [**`.filter`**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) on `$(this)` instead.

Try this:

```js
$( ".inputQuantityUpdate" ).each(function( index ) {
    completed = $(this).filter(":input[type='text']:first").val();
    nc = $(this).filter(":input[type='text']:first").next().val();
    if (nc == "NC") nc = 0;
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```